# RHEL 7.2 - cannot find attached vda disk during install via Mirantis Open Stack

Tags: openstack, rhel7, virtio

In trying to install RHEL 7 from an ISO (instead of deploying from an existing KVM image) in Mirantis Open Stack, I run into Anaconda not being able to find the attached disk - and so installation cannot proceed.

#### There is a 160GB virtio disk (/dev/vda) attached to this image:

[image: instance view]

#### But Anaconda cannot see it:

[image: no disk]

[image: no disk]

The virtio drivers should be standard (as of RHEL 6.4) in the ISO - especially since Red Hat also distributes a KVM image of 7.2 that is "ready to deploy" with Open Stack with the same release date as the ISO media.

Why would the installer not be able to see the attached volume during install? Do I need additional drivers, etc to get it to load?

Comment: Are you able to log into the compute node and verify the running domxml points to an image, and the image path is usable?

Comment: @dyasny - I can check in the morning. But if I use a non-ISO as the image source, it creates normally. And we have been able to build VMs with other ISOs (including Ubuntu and Windows)

Comment: I would look through the `dmesg` output and see if anything interesting shows up there.

Comment: I'd be going about it the openstack way - build a VM, seal it, make sure it's ready to autoconfigure via cloud-init. Do the building part on a KVM host of course. Frankly, I deploy and test hundreds of RHEL 7 installs under openstack every day, and I've never seen this problem, so you either have a faulty initial image, or your distribution is doing something wrong

Comment: @dyasny - the ISO is not faulty: I can use the exact same ISO to install a VM with vSphere, virt-manager, etc. It's only in the context of trying to use the Launch Instance method that it is failing

Comment: So again, back to my first question - what does the domxml look like in this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution used:

Build VM in KVM away from OpenStack, convert into image, and push into OpenStack library

Still want to know why the build-from-ISO route did not work, but it's more important to be able to move ahead with this project.